# Count clicks on element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am new to javascript.I was wondering about how can i get the number of clicks in a paragraph with the `onClick` method in javascript.

The code i have used is

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="avalue"> kdfbkjdf </p>
<script>


var a = document.getElementById('avalue');
a.onClick = function(b) {
console.log(b);
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code doesnt show any errors but when i clicked the paragraph i didnt get the clicked numbers.

How can i acheive with onclick method ??..

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need a counter variable.

Comment: You have a typo. Your `onClick` should be `onclick`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to maintain an external variable to work as a counter and increment it in the handler

```
var clicks = 0; // counter 
var a = document.getElementById('avalue'); // element
a.onclick = function(b) { // onclick not onClick
   console.log(++clicks); // increment it
}
```

From your comment, you could do this

```
a.ondblclick = function(){
   alert(clicks); // double click to know the number of clicks so far
}
```

Comment: but i get the value 0 instead of their sum

Comment: @lovemysql click for sometimes and then double click

Answer (score 4):

Save your click counter in the element's data to avoid the "need" for a global variable:

```
document.getElementById('avalue').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var element = event.currentTarget;
    element.clicks = (element.clicks || 0) + 1;
    console.log(element.clicks);
});
```

and access it anytime under `document.getElementById('avalue').clicks`.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to store the primitive data on the element, but you should probably put it on the bound element instead of the `event.target` just in case he adds nested elements.

Comment: Thanks. I'll change it to `currentTarget`.

Comment: Good call with the addEventListener, hon2a

Comment: @hon2a wow really thanx ..can you tell me how can i find the total of the onclick ..suppose if i clicked one time it shows 1 and if i clicked again it shows two..how can i get the whole sum ??..any ideas

Comment: The number of clicks is (in my code sample) saved in the `click` property right on the `HTMLElement`. So you can get it anytime by `document.getElementById('avalue').clicks`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a counter that you increment each time it's clicked:

```
var b = 0;
var a = document.getElementById('avalue');
a.onclick = function() {
console.log(++b);
}
```

Comment: wow really thanx ..can you tell me how can i find the total of the onclick ..suppose if i clicked one time it shows 1 and if i clicked again it shows two..how can i get the whole sum ??..any ideas

Comment: That's what `b` will be.

Comment: @lovemysql: If you're not sure, then I really recommend taking a step back and reading through some basic JavaScript tutorials. If you just spend a couple days doing that, you'll have the majority of your questions answered. [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net) ... [Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.getElementById('avalue');
var b = 0;
a.onClick = function(b) {
    b++;
    console.log(b);
}
```

Change it to this and you should be able to see the number.