# A Javascript script algorithm for counting the number of mouse clicks on an Html <button>. Using event Listener

Tags: javascript, html, button, addeventlistener

I have a very simple html code that has only one button tag. I need to count the number of mouse clicks on the button using javascript.
[Here is a screenshot of the Javascript code in VScode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRCYt.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question and copy/paste your code. It's much simpler for us to work with code then with images

Comment: Please post the code here so that it'd be easy to copy and execute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count clicks on element with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153750/count-clicks-on-element-with-javascript)

Comment: I have also found it, but it is not with event listener

Comment: Images of code are not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```js
let numberOfClicks = 0;
function addclick() {
  numberOfClicks++;
  document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = numberOfClicks;
}

document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click", addclick);
```

```html
<button id='clickme'>Click me!</button>
<p id='clicks'>0</p>
```

Update: Solution with event listener

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code below can implement count on click functionality.

```js
let clicks = 0;
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
clicks++;
document.querySelector('.clicks').textContent = clicks
})
```

```css
.btn {
    border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 1rem 90px 1rem 2rem;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px;
  background-color: #5086bd;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 9, 61, 0.2) 0px 4px 8px 0px;
  
}
```

```html
<button class="btn"> Click me </button>
<div>
  <p>You have clicked the button <span class="clicks"> 0</span> times</p>
</div>
```